# c - Why pressing enter triggers getchar() to terminate?

Tags: c

As <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not `EOF`, `getchat()` should be able to recognize `\n` when I press Enter.

In C document:

**Return Value** `The obtained character on success or EOF on failure.`

However, when I run

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int c, q = 1;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '"') {
            printf("%s", q ? "``" : "''");
            q = !q;
        }else{
            printf("%c", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There showed the output but the program is not terminated and it is waiting for more input.

> This is "quote"<kbd>Enter</kbd>

output:``` This is ``quote'' ```

[image: press Enter]

I wonder whether the operating system matters because I'm under `OS X10.10` and it is said that **`\r` starts a new line rather than `\n` under OS X**.

Also, I'm not sure whether the debugger matters because I used `Xcode` to run the program.

**`Ctrl-D` would terminate the program and show the output right after my Input.

But `Enter` would output the current `stdin` and then wait for new input.

I don't have any other ideas why this happened so far.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, on OS X. It runs until I press Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D.

Comment: @interjay You're right. I'm sorry for that. But why Enter acts like EOF?

Comment: @RadLexus Ctrl+C is not working for me, but Ctrl+D works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press enter does not terminate your program, it add a new line to the input stream, it won't add an EOF, depends on which shell you are in, you can use Ctrl-D to mark EOF of stdin and terminate your program.

The standard streams are line buffered, and the behavior of line buffered streams are defined by the standard as follows:

> When a stream is line buffered , characters are intended to be
>       transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is
>       encountered. Furthermore, characters are intended to be transmitted as a block to the host
>       environment when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or
>       when input is requested on a line buffered stream that requires the transmission of
>       characters from the host environment.

Comment: But I think `\n` should be in the output if Enter won't add an EOF?

Comment: Yes, precisely, did you see otherwise?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what does 'see otherwise' mean. (I'm not a native speaker). Actually I'm getting more confused now. Does that mean, when I'm typing in the console, the content is not actually going into `stdin`. Only when I press `Enter` does the content be sent into `stdin` and the `stdin` then be tested? Because I put breakpoints in the `while` loop both in `if` and `else` and I found that after pressing Enter the while loop is executed. Also, I don't understand why the previous input be cleaned after pressing `Enter`.

Comment: The standard streams are line buffered, that's why you see the input in terms of lines. Also a new line is not same as EOF.